# Auto-launching apps using URI associations for Windows Phone Universal 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have an application named MyApplication.  What I am trying to do is to do deep linking.
I would like to associate a link that when click on my Windows Phone 8.1 XAML, the application will be launched with the elements passed.

For example:  MyApplication://item/1234 -> will open my application.

I am trying to do this from outside of an application is this possible? for example if I clicked on this link that was in an email, could it be redirected to my application?

Edit:

Here is part of the solution but i am not finding what i really wanted to do:

Uri Activation(XAML)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh779670.aspx

Code:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec

Comment: The link you attached describes exactly what you are asking for: If you register your app for protocol activation in the manifest, it will open once somebody clicks link that matches your protocol. What exactly is missing for you?

Comment: The link that I have attached is if I had another application in which I could do: await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri); and my uri being =    MyApplication://item/1234.
I want to be able to do that but with a link that i can click on that is in an email, sms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can. Create the protocol (something like test:) in your app and deploy it to your machine. Then, in Start>Run type "test:" and your app will load just fine. A link in email? Sure. A link in a web page? Sure. It all works.

> A little more: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/walkthrough-using-windows-8-custom.html

Best of luck!

Comment: is it possible to add URI associate to the URL? I've added the protocols and it works like a charm.

I have a requirement wherein, when user clicks on a url like https ://www.xyz.com/user then User should be redirected to the App or to the store to download the App. How do I do this?